# PowerShell Cmdlets .length attribute for one element result

Tags: powershell, for-loop, powershell-cmdlet

I am using a Cmdlet which can return one or more elements:

```
PS C:\Users\admin> $x = Get-myObjects
PS C:\Users\admin> $x


ComputerName               : test-2
Description                : n/a
Id                         : cbcb1ece-99f5-4478-9f02-65a622df8a98
IsActive                   :
MinNum                     : 0
Name                       : scom-test2-mp
modeType                   : 1
PSComputerName             :
```

If I use length attribute I get nothing.

```
PS C:\Users\admin> $x.length
PS C:\Users\admin>
```

Yet, if the `Get-myObjects` cmdlet returns 2 or more, then it is a collection and I can get `.length` attribute.

How can I get the .length to work if the Get-myObjects cmdlet returns a single object for one object value?

Comment: The three answers you got are fine. I'd just add one bit of info: your code works as is in PowerShell 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always force the result into an array, either when assigning the return value of your cmdlet to a variable:

```
$x = @(Get-myObjects)
$x.Length
```

or "on-demand":

```
$x = Get-myObjects
@($x).Length
```

Comment: I would go for `$x = @(get-myobjects)` That ensures you that you always get an array right away, and you don't have to care about it afterwards.

Comment: I like this solution, especially the first option. `$x = @(Get-myObjects)`

Comment: also, is that specific to PS version? does it work on all versions of powershell?

Comment: It works on at least v2 and v3. Not sure about v1, since I haven't been using that in a while.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Measure-Object` cmdlet. It's a little clunky here because you can't just get the count in an elegant way.

```
$x = Get-myObjects
$x | measure-object
```

Output:

> Count    : 1
>   Average  :
>   Sum      :
>   Maximum  :
>   Minimum  :
>   Property :

If you just want the count:

```
$x | measure-object | select -ExpandProperty Count
```

Output:

> 1

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in this case it is better to use the `foreach` loop of powershell.

[reference of logical loops in PowerShell](http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/logic-using-loops/)

example:

```
foreach($i in $x)
{
  Write-Host $i.Name
}
```

The above example works for both when $x has one element or more.